# MySQL - How to find specific field with comparing two field in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have these two tables:

```
subscription (TABLE)
    subscription_id int (10)
    user_id int (10)
    property_id int (10)
    subscription_plan_id int (10)
    active BIT ()
    start_date timestamp ()
    end_date date ()

subscription_plan (TABLE)
    subscription_plan_id int (10)
    plan_name varchar (100)
    plan_month int (10)
    description varchar (500)
    plan_for char (1)
    price float (12)
    parent_id int (10)
```

and I have written this select SQL query to get data from the two tables:

```
SELECT subscription. * , subscription_plan.plan_name, subscription_plan.plan_month, subscription_plan.parent_id
FROM subscription
JOIN subscription_plan ON subscription.subscription_plan_id = subscription_plan.subscription_plan_id
WHERE subscription.user_id =71
AND subscription.property_id =981
ORDER BY subscription.subscription_plan_id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and I am getting these results:

[image]

Now again I want to get plan name with comparing `parent_id` and `subscription_plan_id` and filter plan name which match.

Check the below image so see what I am trying to do:

[image]

**FOR YOUR REFERENCE:**
[image]

Here is my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01727e/1/0

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub . * , t2.plan_name, t2.plan_month, t1.plan_name, t2.parent_id
FROM subscription_plan AS t1
LEFT JOIN subscription_plan AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.subscription_plan_id
JOIN subscription AS sub ON t2.subscription_plan_id = sub.subscription_plan_id
WHERE t2.plan_name IS NOT NULL
AND sub.user_id =71
AND sub.property_id =981
ORDER BY sub.subscription_plan_id ASC
```

i hope it's working

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer regarding what's in your code that will solve the problem of OP.

Comment: Your code is working prefect for me as I explian in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need something [like](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01727e/13)

```
SELECT mytable.*, sp.plan_name AS 'parent_plan_id'
FROM (SELECT subscription. * , subscription_plan.plan_name, subscription_plan.plan_month, subscription_plan.parent_id as "new_parent_id"
FROM subscription
JOIN subscription_plan ON subscription.subscription_plan_id = subscription_plan.subscription_plan_id
WHERE subscription.user_id =71
AND subscription.property_id =981) AS mytable 
INNER JOIN subscription_plan sp
ON mytable.new_parent_id = sp.parent_id
AND mytable.plan_month = sp.plan_month
```

Comment: Can you provid me in my SQL Fiddle as I am not too good sql. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for supporting me but results are wrong. Check my screenshot which I have added in my question.

Comment: Dont you get parent plan name now?

Comment: I have checked your fiddle and only two records are possible in my query.

Comment: In fact you have three rows for plan id 1. So which one you want to show as name?

Comment: I have checked your fiddle but I want `be bold` in `PARENT_PLAN_ID` rows. Check my screenshot that helps you to understand want I am wanting.

Comment: Yeah i see that and logic behind it is?

Comment: That's what i am saying only if you could explain why be bold and not the other two with parent id as 1? Why you have three rows with plan id 1 then?

Comment: I am already fetching `plan_name` in my sql query but I also want to get `plan_name` based on this two fields with matching `parent_id` & `subscription_plan_id`

Comment: I have added on screenshot check that with explaining with arrows :)